# Chart JS - single lines (points) tooltips

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, chart.js

How do I get to ChartJS returns only the value of a point on the graph (on mouse over), instead of the whole dataset?

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div style="width:30%">
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="1000"></canvas>

        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><div id="placeholder" height="450" width="600"></div>
```

```
    <script>
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : [<?php echo $_SESSION['GRAFICO2']; ?>],
        datasets : [<?php echo $_SESSION[$_GET['vGrafico']]; ?>

        ]

    }


window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {bezierCurve: false, pointDot : true, datasetStroke : true, showTooltips: true, pointHitDetectionRadius : 2, offsetGridLines : true, TooltipTemplate: "<%= label %> - <%= data %>"});
    legend(document.getElementById('placeholder'), lineChartData);
}

</script>
```

Like this
[now - than](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjPYN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the `showTooltip` of the chart and `inRange` methods of the points.

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
...
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

// Chart.js replaces the base inRange function for Line points with a function that checks only the x coordinate
// we replace it with the original inRange fucntion (one that checks both x and y coordinates)
myChart.datasets.forEach(function(dataset){
  dataset.points.forEach(function(point){
    point.inRange = Chart.Point.prototype.inRange;
  });
});

// Chart.js shows a multiTooltip based on the index if it detects that there are more than one datasets
// we override it to show a single tooltip for the inRange element
myChart.showTooltip = function(ChartElements, forceRedraw) {
  // this clears out the existing canvas - the actual Chart.js library code is a bit more optimized with checks for whether active points have changed, etc.
  this.draw();
  // draw tooltip for active elements (if there is one)
  Chart.helpers.each(ChartElements, function(Element){
      var tooltipPosition = Element.tooltipPosition();
      new Chart.Tooltip({
        x: Math.round(tooltipPosition.x),
        y: Math.round(tooltipPosition.y),
        xPadding: this.options.tooltipXPadding,
        yPadding: this.options.tooltipYPadding,
        fillColor: this.options.tooltipFillColor,
        textColor: this.options.tooltipFontColor,
        fontFamily: this.options.tooltipFontFamily,
        fontStyle: this.options.tooltipFontStyle,
        fontSize: this.options.tooltipFontSize,
        caretHeight: this.options.tooltipCaretSize,
        cornerRadius: this.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
        text: Chart.helpers.template(this.options.tooltipTemplate, Element),
        chart: this.chart,
        custom: this.options.customTooltips
      }).draw();
    }, this);
}
```

The obvious downside is that if there are 2 (or more) points close together, you'll see multiple tooltips that might possible overlap.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/v7mtz64o/